# How to retrieve data from datepicker form?

Tags: datepicker, zurb-foundation

I use zurb foundation datepicker to get date of my date. The tutorial as [here](http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example/example.html). But my question, how to retrieve data from `<input type="text" class="span2" id="dp1">` of mm-dd-yyyy? So I can get mm=? dd=? yyyy=?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may not retrieve the information split into day, month, year variable directly as you are using a input text which only contains a string value. You must parse the value yourself to get that information. Here is an example in javascript:

```
var data = dp1.val();
var day = data.substr(0,2);
var month = data.substr(3,5);
var year = data.substr(6,10);
```